# UITextView and UILabel Subview Properties are nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In one of my view controllers, I've got the following structure:

```
+-View
 +-Scroll View 1
  +-UIView
   +-Scroll View 2
```

...and I'm adding three subviews into Scroll View 2, one of which contains a series of UITextViews and UILabels as a form-like structure.

The problem I'm seeing is that when I try to access the properties that refer to those controls from the view controller level, they are coming up nil. However, if I set a breakpoint in awakeFromNib inside the UIView that contains the UITextFields and UILabels, the properties are valid... it's almost like the reference disappears.

I can clearly see that they exist, and if I do the following in the debug console after setting a breakpoint, I definitely get the view graph output to the console:

```
po [self.profileEditView recursiveDescription]
```

Does this sound familiar to anyone, and if so, how can I remedy it?

One thing I'm thinking of doing is just not trying to access those properties directly, since the goal is to get the view controller to be the delegate of those UITextView controls so it can respond to becoming the first responder by adjusting Scroll View 1's position when each text view gets focus. It's just more of a hassle, but if that's what I have to do I'll go that route.

I've just never seen this happen before so I thought it was pretty strange. There's definitely a lot going on in this view controller.

Additional Details:

- The View Controller is defined in a Storyboard.
- The UIView subviews added at runtime have XIBs that I load programatically.

Comment: Are the properties you're trying to access `IBOutlet` annotated and are they hooked up in the xib(s)?

Comment: In what method you are trying to access them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered what the problem is... I was inadvertently instantiating *another* subview as a subview inside initWithFrame (don't ask me why I was doing that... I think I was under the impression that I needed to do that to instantiate the XIB at that point), so the properties on the nested subview were valid but the properties of the top-level view (the one contained in Scroll View 2) were all nil.

I had a five-minute conversation with a developer in NZ and he asked about what I was doing there and it became readily apparent that what I needed to do was instantiate the view and its NIB in the view controller with:

```
ProfileEditView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProfileEditView" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

...instead of instantiating it with initWithFrame.

Thanks for the help, however!